# Weird positioning elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have something really weird, im building a simple parralax scrolling rotating infobox.
I made a square in the center and the elements inside act really weird with positioning.

But when I resize my window, everything pops into the right positioning.
I have absolutely no idea why or how this is happening. Anyone has an idea?

Greetings, Chris.

Link : http://62866.glr-imd.nl/test.html
(scroll to see it rotate)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rW9Dv/ Scrolling element does not work in there.

```
    position:fixed;
```

Maybe position fixed conflicts with the JS?

Comment: Post your code. Done expect from us to inspect your site

Comment: which browser are you using? and yes a fiddle would be great http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Done @laaposto but I dont think it will work.

Comment: @caramba Chrome for mac, the latest verson

Comment: in chrome Version 32.0.1700.107 and FF 27.0 nothing changes on browser resize

Comment: @caramba I am also running Chrome 32.0.1700.107, and it does not work at my browser.

Answer (score 0):

The `margin-left` on you `#textveld_2` in the css might be the problem.

Try changing it from -250px to -249px, it pops into the right place for me when i tried this.

Comment: That does not do the trick for me, the weird in thing is: When I open "inspect element" it resizes the screen and then everything is in the right place. So I can never check why it does that...

Comment: Yeah I do that too, but then I refresh the page with developer tools active and it make it go back to being the bad version.

Comment: Do any of you have a clue what this might be?