# Element positioning conflicting

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have something really weird, im building a simple parralax scrolling rotating infobox. I made a square in the center and the elements inside act really weird with positioning.

But when I resize my window, everything pops into the right position. I have absolutely no idea why or how this is happening. Anyone has any idea?

Greetings, Chris.

[Link](http://62866.glr-imd.nl/test.html) :  (scroll to see it rotate)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rW9Dv/):  Scrolling element does not work in there.

I have a feeling that it conflicts with the javascript, i have tried resizing my central container, but that does not work either.

```
#container {
width:500px;
height:500px;
top:50%;
left:50%;
margin-left:-250px;
margin-top:-250px;
background:#FFFFFF;
padding:1px !important;
}
#textveld_1 {
    position:fixed;
    top:0%;
    left:0%;
    height:130px;
    width:250px;
    margin-top:60px;
    margin-left:-60px; 
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(90deg);
}
```

The 4 "textveld_#" are rotated 90 -> 180 -> 270 -> 0

Comment: *Scrolling element does not work in there.* You haven't included jQuery library and other required 3rd party scripts

Comment: Why ask the same question twice? You can edit the old one!http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21784690/weird-positioning-elements

Comment: @Mr.Alien you dont need jquery for this script, it is rotating already. What browser are you using?

I also feel that this is more of a CSS conflict than a JS confict, but then I again I have no clue on what this could be causing the weird positioning.

Comment: @laaposto nobody replies there, and I really need a solution...

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: skrollr is not defined`